# Can I overlay calendars in Office365 (pre-upgrade version)

Tags: icalendar, office365

How do I overlay calendars in Office 365.

I know how to do this in Outlook, but can't find how to do it in Office 365. When I open another calendar, either a work colleagues or an iCal I've imported, it shows side-by-side with my own calendar but not on top of it to allow me to see a unified view.

**Edit**: Here is the Office 365 I'm talking about - It is the pre-upgrade version it seems: 
[image: screen grab of my owa email client]

and this is how the calendar looks:
[image: screen grab of my owa calendar]

What I want to achieve is for the `ics` calendar to overlay the main calendar. So that when the ics calendar contains time table information, lectures, seminars etc. it's easy to see everything at once. There's the potential to add in other ics calendars too, favourite football teams, sports society events etc. If they each have to be displayed alongside each other (as my 2nd screenshot shows) that is going to be pretty complicated to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you speaking about Office 365 pre-upgrade, or new Office 365?
With the new Office 365, I think calendars overlap by default, and you can change that on the upper right of the calendar view.

Comment: This is the new Office 365; the University I work for has ditched it's internal Exchange servers in favour of "moving to the cloud" (though I confess I'm not 100% certain and the internal politics of these places make it really hard to find out for certain), but I'm 99% sure we're not on a pre-upgrade / beta or anything like that.   
I've hunted through the options but can't see anywhere that lets me overlay calendars - only view them side by side.

The goal is to use an iCal for each student timetable, possibly for sports clubs and other social events. So really overlay is essential

Comment: Does it look like this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-suite-help/getting-started-in-outlook-web-app-for-office-365-HA103267190.aspx?CTT=1.

Comment: Your screenshot is the pre-upgrade Office. Not the new one.

Comment: Ahhh; didn't realise that. So does the pre-upgrade version allow calendar overlays?

Comment: No, unfortunatly it does not seem so.

Answer (score -1):

You can overlay calendars by starting with 1 calendar open, then open a second, then click on the second calendar, then click on the view tab and click on overlay.  Using this procedure you can overlay multiple calendars.  If you click on overlay when there are no new calendars it will unoverlay the last calendar you have added.

Comment: This does not work on the pre-upgrade version of O365, which I have specified in my question. There is no view tab as you can see from my screenshot.